# Converting animations from artist into code

Tags: ios, animation, mobile, cocos2d-iphone, uikit

During our development process, we've run into many instances where the artist/design would mock up an animation and the developer would be tasked with converting into code -- whether it's UIView animations or CCActions in a game engine like Cocos2D.

The problem is we don't have a good way of turning the animations provided by the artist/designer, usually in the form of Flash/After Effects or similar tool, directly into code. The developer has to spend a lot of time figuring out the exact animation parameters and end up with code that looks like this:

```
CAAnimationGroup *(^groupedAnimation)(CGMutablePathRef curvedPath, NSTimeInterval delay) = ^(CGMutablePathRef curvedPath, NSTimeInterval delay) {

    CGFloat moveTime = 1.6;

    CABasicAnimation *scaling = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.scale"];
    scaling.fromValue = @1.;
    scaling.toValue = @0.05;
    scaling.beginTime = delay;
    scaling.duration = moveTime;
    scaling.removedOnCompletion = NO;
    scaling.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
    scaling.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn];

    CABasicAnimation *opacity = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];
    opacity.fromValue = @1.;
    opacity.toValue = @0.1;
    opacity.beginTime = delay + moveTime-0.6;
    opacity.duration = 0.5;
    opacity.removedOnCompletion = NO;
    opacity.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
    opacity.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear];

    CAKeyframeAnimation *path = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
    path.beginTime = delay;
    path.duration = moveTime;
    path.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear];
    path.path = curvedPath;
    path.calculationMode = kCAAnimationPaced;
    path.removedOnCompletion = NO;
    path.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;

    CAAnimationGroup *group = [CAAnimationGroup animation];
    group.animations = @[scaling, opacity, path];
    group.beginTime = 0;
    group.duration = moveTime+delay;
    group.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionDefault];
    group.removedOnCompletion = NO;
    group.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;

    return group;
};
```

Figuring out the parameters of these animations in code is a very manual process and involves a lot of eyeballing the animation mock and iteratively narrowing in on a value that looks good. Generally very time consuming and tedious.

Is there a better process? What's the industry standard for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at SpriteKit scene editor,

In XCode-> Create new project -> Game -> Game Technology = SpriteKit

Then open Scene Editor by clicking on file with extension .sks in project navigator

You can experiment animations and achieve above without single line of code

Comment: hmm, but my issue is specifically with UIKit (UIView animations) and cocos2D, neither of which is compatible with the spritekit scene editor.

Comment: you can use SpriteKit editor for experiments till you are satisfied with animation behaviour, once OK you start coding using UIView or something else, sprite kit editor helps you design and test animations without coding ...

Comment: Right, that's the part where we're already accomplishing using Flash/after effects. We can mock the animation up fine, but translating it into code is the tedious part because we don't have a good way of converting the mock into the right parameters for UIView animation calls.